# Word that sounds like Klabacha to describe an house

Tags: meaning, word-usage, word-choice, single-word-request

When crossing a specific old house which was abandoned, one friend used an expression for it that sounded like *Klabacha* / *Klabaca*. Since he only speaks german, i presume it to be a German word.

Googling couldn't spot such word and translating "old house" or "empty house" gives no similar results (only *verlassenes Haus* or *altes Haus*). Also didn't find such word in my German - English / English - German dictionary (from Porto Editora, portuguese firm).

What's the real word and its meaning?

Comment: Might it have been "[Baracke](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baracke)"?

Comment: @TorstenLink definitely not baracke, that is like the portuguese "barraca" and I'd have done the association right away

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I took a [closer](https://books.google.de/books?id=FZd3DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA167&lpg=PA167&dq=klabache%20rotwelsch&source=bl&ots=1ynNZ_OYVV&sig=ACfU3U1xUJN12JD_FtQleOI70uGVmOp0GA&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiF6sPsoNrtAhXRzaQKHcdnAEMQ6AEwBXoECBEQAg#v=onepage&q=klabache%20rotwelsch&f=false) [look](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masematte#Beispiele%5B4%5D) and the word seems to have a [Rotwelsch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotwelsch) origin.

> Klabacha - baufälliges, verwahrlostes Haus

meaning "dilapidated shabby house"

**Original answer:**

There are several roughly similar sounding words. But the most likely is

> [Kabache](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Kabache)

what means "little/primitive hut" or "pub".

[pronunciation](https://educalingo.com/de/dic-de/kabache) (and some more information)

Comment: Oh so it is writen as it sounds!!!